# std::vector memory handling

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to google and search an answer to my question, but I couldn't find any valid explanation hence I am posting my question here. Following is my sample code and output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    Node(){
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "Node created. " << this <<'\n';
    }
    ~Node(){
        data = 0;
        std::cout << "Node destroyed. " << this <<'\n';
    }
} Node;

int main() {
    std::vector<Node> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++)
       vec.push_back( *(new Node));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Node created. 0x9e0da10
Node created. 0x9e0da30
Node destroyed. 0x9e0da20
Node destroyed. 0x9e0da40
Node destroyed. 0x9e0da44
```

Why is there an extra destroy and why are created objects different from destroyed object?

Comment: You are not tracing the copy constructor.  Also, C++ is not Java -- all you need is `vec.push_back(Node());`

Comment: also `vec.push_back( *(new Node));` causes me physical pain

Comment: That whole 'typedef struct Node {...} Node' thing tells me you're being taught C++ by a C person and need to find a better book or instructor

Comment: Arghhefggh my insides have turned to mush

Comment: Let's not scare OP away from C++ by describing our aches :)

Comment: In general, when you want to follow the lifetime, you also instrument the constructors and assignment operators that are supplied implicitly! That is, the copy constructor,  default constructor (even if it's not explicit in the class) and copy assignment operator.  You can make a reusable `class noisy` that you inherit where you want to add this instrumentation.

Comment: @JDługosz inherit?  Unless you want to end up in Slicing Hell, that last part should probably be "that you compose into classes when you want to add this instrumentation."  And you'd want to instrument `swap` as well.

Comment: Not at all. Make it a private base class. You never declare variables *of* that instrument type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you would add a copy constructor you would find out the answer:

```
Node created. 0x60200000df90
Node copied: 0x60200000df70  Source: 0x60200000df90
Node created. 0x60200000df50
Node copied: 0x60200000df34  Source: 0x60200000df50
Node copied: 0x60200000df30  Source: 0x60200000df70
Node destroyed. 0x60200000df70
Node destroyed. 0x60200000df34
Node destroyed. 0x60200000df30
```

So when you have added the second element to the vector there will not be enough capacity and the vector has to resize the storage and copy all old elements (in this case only one such element) to the new space. That's why one extra copy constructor was called.

And yes, in C++ all standard containers requires that object should be copy or move constructible, so you don't have to create them on the heap (as in Java). The more correct code would be like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vector"


struct Node {
  int data;
  Node() : data(0) {
    std::cout << "Node created. " << this <<'\n';
  }

  Node(const Node &n) : data(n.data) {
    std::cout << "Node copied: " << this << "  Source: " << &n << std::endl;
  }

  ~Node(){
    // You don't need data = 0 in destructor
    std::cout << "Node destroyed. " << this <<'\n';
  }

};

int main() {
  std::vector<Node> vec;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
    vec.push_back(Node());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This makes so much sense , thanx a ton

Comment: If I could give this answer +100 I would.  All the other answers are trying to explain *why* instead of *what* (or at least don't demonstrate the *what*).  The *why* is only useful if you understand *what* is happening.

Answer (score 38):

`vec.push_back( *(new Node));` is an immediate memory leak.

First you dynamically allocate a `Node`, then you **copy** that `Node` into the vector. The copy operation is what creates the new object, which is why `this` is different.

The original (dynamically allocated) `Node` is never deallocated, but the copies are when the destructor of the vector runs (i.e. at the end of the function).

Why three destructor calls instead of two? That's caused by the automatic reallocation of the vector when you `push_back`. It moves/copies its elements to a new memory location, destroying the old elements.

---

Note that normally, when you simply want a vector of `n` default-constructed elements, you'd do:

```
std::vector<Node> vec(2);
```

This calls `Node()` (the default constructor) for elements `vec[0]` and `vec[1]`, and you don't need a loop (or dynamic allocation).

Answer (score 12):

When you add an element to a vector you construct a new copy through the **copy constructor** (or the move constructor).

So a line like `vec.push_back( *(new Node));` does two things.

- It constructs a new Node dynamically allocated with `new`.
- It copies the new node into the vector. This means a new node is created through the *copy constructor*.
- The original node is never deallocated (this is called a *memory leak*)

This version of your code with the copy constructor might provide you with some insight : http://ideone.com/ow5YOI

Comment: Your 1st line is not correct. Adding via `push_back` with an _rvalue_ can use the move constructor. Adding via `emplace_back` constructs in-place, no copying.

Comment: [in response to pre edit version of comment] If you're worried about including too much info, then simplification can be good, but IMHO only when done completely like "in this particular case, the copy ctor is used", whereas _partially_ simplifying by omitting important info can generate confusion later. But I'm just being general. :)

Comment: Yes, I firgured out that you were right just after posting the comment :')

Answer (score 4):

Your loop is equivalent to

```
vec.push_back( *(new Node));
vec.push_back( *(new Node));
```

what happens is:

1. `new Node` allocates memory and creates a Node (**Node created**)
2. `push_back` allocates new storage
3. `push_back` creates a `Node` object in the vector's storage, using the (implicit) copy constructor. (no message printed)
4. The `Node` you created is leaked (2 Nodes exist, 1 unreachable)
5. `new Node` allocates memory and creates a Node (**Node created**)
6. `push_back` allocates new storage, and copies/moves the existing elements (no message printed)
7. `push_back` deletes its old contents (**Node deleted**)
8. `push_back` creates another `Node` in the vector, using the (implicit) copy constructor (no message printed)
9. The `Node` you created is leaked (4 Nodes exist, 2 unreachable)

When the vector goes out of scope, the two copies it contains are deleted. (**Node deleted**, **Node deleted**)

---

You would normally write

```
vec.push_back(Node())
```

or

```
vec.emplace_back()
```

instead.

---

If you want to really see what's going on, you ought to create a non-default copy constructor:

```
Node(const Node& other){
    data = other.data;
    std::cout << "Node created. " << this
              << " from " << &other << std::endl;
}
```