# C++ vector pushback method and temporary object creation

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy-constructor, push-back

Below is the signature of vector pushback method in C++.

```
 void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

Now below is code

```
class MyInt
{
   int *a;
public:
  MyInt(int n):a(new int(n)){cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;}
   ~MyInt(){cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;}
   void show(){
   cout<<*a<<endl;
   }
 };


 void vector_test(vector<MyInt> &v)
 {
    MyInt m1(1);
    MyInt m2(2);
    v.push_back(m1);   
    v.push_back(m2);
 }



Output
-------------
constructor called
constructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
1
2
destructor called
destructor called
```

Here we see that for 2 objects which is created in vector_test function causes 2 times 
constructor invocation.
But for destructor it got invoked 5 times.

Now my doubts and questions are

1. How come number of constructor and destructor calls are not matching?
2. I understand that there are some temporary objects getting created. But how this mechanism is working?
3. Just to test, I tried to provide a copy constructor but it causes compilation failure. What could be the reason?
4. Is there some logic inside which is copying the contents of m1 and m2 into new objects and puts in to the container?

I would really appreciate if someone explain this in detail. Thanks..

Comment: You missed to track the copy constructor (there's one generated by the compiler).

Comment: And once you get the copy constructor written and tracked, note that the number of times the object is created and destroyed is dependent on the compiler, compiler optimizations, etc.

Comment: " I tried to provide a copy constructor but it causes compilation failure. What could be the reason?" show and maybe we can tell. Otherwise best anyone can say is you probably have a syntax error.

Comment: Yes you missed to track the copy constructor. What pei said.

Comment: Please add the copy constructor, there are meany reasons the compilation might fail.
Also it would be nice to free the memory, other might need it later. Or even better don't use pointers.

Comment: @Neeraj So you couldn't get the copy constructor corrected, you knew that it was necessary, but still posted your findings??  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Putting line numbers in your code makes it harder for people to cut and paste what you've written, which in turn makes it less likely that folks will help you out. It doesn't matter here, because for experienced programmers the answer is obvious (we've all run into it in the past), but in general, don't do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate / closely related Q from a while ago: [std::vector memory handling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36568377/3425536)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response.

Comment: @user4581301: My mistake. Yes there was silly syntax error in copy constructor. I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thank you for your help. Could you please provide more information on temporary object creation? Actually I am looking out for possible
sequence of events when temporary object is created and how copy constructor helps in these situations.

Comment: Don't forgot all the compiler generated constructors. To add real tracking you need to compensate for the copy and move constructors.

Comment: useful `g++` options for the sake of observing: `-fno-elide-constructors`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add logging also for copy constructor:

```
MyInt(const MyInt& rhs):a(new int(*rhs.a)){cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;}
```

Some constructor calls are allowed by compiler to be elided, ie. in following line:

```
MyInt m1 = 1;
```

you might expect copy constructor to be first called to instantiate temporary `MyInt(1)` then a copy constructor called with this temporary. So you would see:

```
constructor called // for temporary
copy constructor called // for m1
destructor called       // for m1
destructor called  // for temporary
```

but because of copy elision compiler will directly instantiate your `m1` instance using `MyInt(int n)` constructor, even though your copy constructor has side effects (std::cout is used). So no above `// for temporary` logs will be present.

To see this with gcc use: `-fno-elide-constructors` option which diasbles copy constructor elision.

Also it is a good practice to make constructors such as `MyInt(int n)` explicit, this is to disallow making `MyInt` object instance by mistake - you will have to make it explicit, i.e. `MyInt var; var = static_cast<MyInt>(1);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the compiler can potentially add five methods if you don't provide them. Im this case you are being affected by the compiler generated copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MyInt
{
   int *a;
public:
  MyInt(int n):a(new int(n)){cout<<"constructor called"<<endl;}
  MyInt(MyInt const& copy): a(new int(*copy.a)) {cout<<"copy constructor called"<<endl;}
  MyInt(MyInt&& move): a(move.a) {move.a = nullptr; cout<<"move constructor called"<<endl;}
   ~MyInt(){cout<<"destructor called"<<endl;}
   void show(){
   cout<<*a<<endl;
   }
 };


 void vector_test(vector<MyInt> &v)
 {
    MyInt m1(1);
    MyInt m2(2);
    v.push_back(m1);
    v.push_back(m2);
 }

 int main()
 {
    vector<MyInt> v;
    vector_test(v);
 }
```

When I run this I get

```
batman> ./a.out
constructor called
constructor called
copy constructor called
copy constructor called
copy constructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
destructor called
```

Note: You are leaking memory from the destructor.

This is also why we have the `emplace_back()` interface. This will reduce the number of copies of the object that are created. Additionally when optimizations are enabled you will see that some of those object are not copied but created in-place.

```
 void vector_test(vector<MyInt> &v)
 {
    MyInt m1(1);
    MyInt m2(2);

    // Can use emplace back
    v.emplace_back(1); // Created the object in-place in the vector.

    // Or you can use a temorary.
    v.push_back(2);  // Compiler sees there is a single argument constructor
                     // and will insert the constructor to convert a 2 into
                     // MyInt object.

    v.push_back(MyInt(3)); // Or you can create a temporary explicitly.
 }
```